# Unable to extract the tar file in python because of permission issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tarfile

I am unable to extract the tar file in python.

This is the code base am using to extract the tar file in Python.

```
file_path = os.path.join(extracted_tar_files, file.strip('.tar'))
tf = tarfile.open(os.path.join(files_directory, file))
tf.extractall(file_path)
tf.close()
```

Some of the tar files are working fine. Some of the tar files am getting the following error.

> *** PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\home\piercer\etc.sudoers'

Can you please help here. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be Unix question rather than a Python question. Why don't you try extracting in the command line with `tar` and fix the permissions?

Comment: @firefrorefiddle That is working on normal windows WinZip module. I need this extraction in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file seems to belong to someone else and you seem to have no read permissions. as is to be expected for a sudoers file. you could change the permissions:

```
$ sudo -E chown $USER /home/piercer/etc.sudoers
```

Comment: I am using windows 10. The above command seems to the Linux command, Can you please share the windows command. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
tar.extractall(file_path, numeric_owner=True)
```

This creates file owner by the user who runs the script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).